# MVVM Access Model from View

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm

I'm new to .net and MVVM designmodel. I'm stuck now, because in the codebehind file of one of my Views, I need to get the corresponding Model as an object. How is the relationship here? Is it possible, and is it "the right way to do it"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The View should access the ViewModel, which wraps the Model, hiding it from the View. If you need to access properties of the Model from the View, get the ViewModel to expose them as properties that the View can bind to.

Comment: Okay, i figured the answer was something like that. But i still have some problems.
When i click on a view 1 of type A i want it to save its corresponding model in the viewmodel. when i click on view 2 of type A i also want it to save its corresponding model in the same viewmodel. so far, i only know how to save itself(the view) not the model :/

Answer (score 2):

MVVM doesn't forbid the View to access the Model directly. That's a common misunderstanding in the MVVM community.

Your ViewModel can expose the underlying Model so that the View can access the model directly.

Binding:

```
{Binding Model.Title}
```

Code Behind:

```
((MyViewModel)DataContext).Title
```

The **ViewModel** (EmailClient) sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)** shows how to access the Model from the View.

Answer (score 1):

**ViewModel should have absolutely no knowledge of the view. View should use DataBinding only so no knowledge of the model or ViewModel.**

If you need to interact with the view, it all must be through *DataBinding*. Only on exceptional cases you should resort to code-behind.

So have a **property on the ViewModel** and **bind** it to the view.

Comment: He wants to access the Model from the View, not the other way round.

Comment: Ok, great but I assume the View can use the classes defined by ViewModel for the properties it exposes ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class MyView : Window
{
     private MyViewModel aModel;

     public MyView()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         aModel = new MyViewModel();
         this.DataContext = aModel();
}
```

Now the view will change its controls databindings that bound to public properties of the ViewModel.